# dispatch($RequestJob); Laravel6

Tags: php, laravel-6.2

I am using Laravel 6.11.9, this same code was working in 5.7.

I am getting error message:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
>   Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\SearchApi::__construct(), 1 passed in /projects/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/Dispatchable.php on line 16 and exactly 3 expected "

in line `app/Jobs/SearchApi.php:41` which is

```
public function __construct($city, $start, $end)
{
    $this->city = $city;
    $this->start = $start;
    $this->end = $end;
    // dump ($city); //
}
```

So I am passing 3 variables from controller to job.

```
class SearchController extends Controller
//  saves data to SearchTable 
    $search = new Search();
    $search->city = request('city');
    $search->start_date =     $start ;
    $search->end_date =       $end;
    $search->save();

    $PrhApiRequestJob = (new SearchApi($city,$start, $end )); 
    SearchApi::dispatch($PrhApiRequestJob);
```

1) What am I missing from my "dispatch" ?
   what has been changed from 5.7 to 6.x ?

From Laravel 6.x documentation says:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    // Create podcast...
    ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast);
}
```

Thanks Mika.

Comment: Have you tried `SearchApi::dispatch($city, $start, $end);` ?

Comment: Resolved my own issue: 

SearchApi::dispatch($city,$start, $end );

and commented out : $PrhApiRequestJob = (new SearchApi($city,$start, $end )); 

Also I have installed Laravel/Telescope which told me http error "500"
that helped me investigate this error deeper.

Comment: sorry I did  not see your update.